# How do I merge/dissolve two polygons within one shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, merge, dissolve, adjacency

I have a shapefile composed of many polygons. I want to merge/combine/dissolve some adjacent polygons that I have selected within the shapefile into one polygon without any slivers or lines left in between.

I do not want to extract the polygons. I just want to combine the attributes of different adjacent polygon features within the existing shapefile

[image]

Essentially I want the below image but not extracted and separate, I want to do the merge internally in the shapefile

[image]

Comment: Please mark the answer complete if your issue is resolved, and it's the solution you expect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a little tricky given that the dissolve/union simply extracts separate shapefile. Here is how you could do that:

**STEP 1:** In the menu item go to: VIEW>TOOLBAR, and then toggle on "Advanced Digitizing Toolbar" and "Digitizing Toolbar".
Your toolbar will look as in the image, after step 1:

[image]

**STEP 2:** Toggle on "EDITING MODE" with that pencil icon you see in the image above/below, and `select features` from the map view which needs to be merged together.
[image]

**STEP 3:** Select "MERGE (POLYGON) FEATURE" tool from the `Advanced Digitizing Toolbar`. You will now see the option to select feature attribute to preserve after merging. Based on your requirement you can select the best from there.

4. Click on `Save>Toggle off editing mode`. (see image below for reference)
   [image]

Comment: Excellent, this is the answer